# How to set global variables from database in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm facing the same problem very often in various projects - I need to set some global variables from `database` and be able to receive them in anywhere in laravel - views, controllers, models. Is it possible? Or what is the most easy way to do this?

Why I need this? For language translations. I need them not cached and saved in file. For website options which can be taken from any place of app. For website language to set, because I don't want to make /language/ prefix on url.

Sorry if this question can be a duplicate, but none of the answers in similar questions worked in a way I have explained.

Comment: If you set your DB model(s) correctly, you should get all related/relevant data with logged in user session. Not meaning you need to store all data in session, but if you set relations between tables correct way, you can eager load any kind of data you need from session `Auth::id()` or session `Auth::user()`. If I am not misunderstanding something.

Comment: You can try view composers for sharing data globally to all views and define variables in base controller to access them in controllers which inherit base controller. I hope it may help..

Comment: @Tpojka if sessions will be disabled on browser then my site will fail because these options are strictly needed for it to load... So I can't use sessions :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) for sharing data globally to all views.

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    //get value from database
    $options = Model::where('domain_name', \Request::server("SERVER_NAME"))->get();
    //render to view
    $view->with('options', $options);
}
```

The `$options` variable (model) would be available in every view.

To share data with all controllers define variables in base controller to access them in controllers which inherit base controller

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public $options = Model::where('domain_name', \Request::server("SERVER_NAME"))->get();
}
```

you can access it using

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        //access here using
        $x = $this->options;
    }
}
```

Like this you can create a base model and use the inherit property to access data globally in models.

Hope it will be useful for you. The `options` variable may contain all the options from database.

Comment: it looks that composers is the best way to solve this problem. By the way - I want to completely avoid sessions, because it will be public site without sessions and options should be loaded in every page depends on to what domain website is given, because it will be multi-site platform. Thanks!! I will leave question open for a while if someone would suggest anything more for few days if it is possible

Comment: can you provide some example based explanation?

Comment: it should work like this:
1. before rendering app receive website domain
2. receive ~20 strings from the database by current domain name
3. share strings(options) to all views, controllers and etc (before they are rendered)
Thank you!!

Comment: thank you! I think it would work. But I will need few weeks to test it in various different ways. Thank you once again my friend :)

Comment: Take your time and let me know the result.. 

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to create a helper class:

1> Add line to composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ],
```

2> Create file:

```
app/Http/helpers.php
```

3> Add code:

```
function o($code = null) {
$option = \Option::where('code', $code)->first();
return $option->value;
}
```

4> Use where you need:

```
echo o('option_code')
```

This works in Controller and View, before any render if called. Here can be checked session, config, cookies and etc.

Comment: This is cool and would be more effective than my answer, as you don't have to write separate code for controllers and views..

Comment: Your answer has inspired my to try this!! :)

Answer (score 0):

the best way to access a variable everywhere in your project is using sessions. you can store everything in sessions and access it everywhere in your controllers, models and views.

Read the topic: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#using-the-session

Comment: There are variables I don't want user to have in sessions, plus I'm thinking about crawling boots - if there will session not working, the website will be not working also, because some options are critical